# write file into spring boot folder

Tags: spring-boot, relative-path

my spring boot project structure is like this

> src
>   |-main
>   |--|-java
>   |--|-resources
>   static
>   |-css
>   |-images
>   |-js

now I want to write a file into the static/images folder 
I tried to new File like 
`BufferedOutputStream stream =new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("static/images")));`it will throw `"No such file or directory" exception`

but in other html file I can get the js by `"js/jsFile.js"`

Answer (score 3):

`new File("static/images")` is right
I used `new File("/static/images")` so I got an Exception

Answer (score 1):

I was in the situation where using Spring Boot I had to save the image into one directory which is accessed statically.

Below code worked perfect

```
byte[] imageByteArray ....
String fileName = "image.png";
String fileLocation = new File("static\\images").getAbsolutePath() + "\\" + fileName;
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileLocation);
fos.write(imageByteArray);
fos.close();
```

Hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

@zhuochen shen is correct.

The thing is to happen me is Eclipse doesn't show write file. So I looked at file explore. File is writing correctly.

```html
    try {
            Path path=Paths.get("static/images/"+productDto.getImage().getOriginalFilename());
            Files.write(path,productDto.getImage().getBytes());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5edP.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPC3B.png)